# Как вывести данные определенного пользователя vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-router

Здравствуете, уважаемые программисты. Я хочу при нажатии на кнопку вывести данные определенного пользователя, по типу: username, для начала. Данные я беру из json файла. На страницу у меня выводятся циклом все пользователи, а точнее их имена, хотелось бы чтобы при нажатии на кнопку возле пользователя вывелись определенные данные, которые есть в json файле. Вроде подробно расписал, как это сделать я не понимаю, хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение. У меня при нажатии на кнопку выводятся данные всех пользователей,а не определенного возле которого нажата кнопка. Почему я понимаю, потому что перебираю циклом, но по другому в голову не лезет((

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </nav>
    <div class="user" v-for="users of data" :key="users.id">
      <p class="oneuser">{{ users.name }}</p>
      <button class="info" @click="getInfo">+</button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="get">
      <div v-for="info of data" :key="info.id">
        <p>{{ info.username }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
      nameUser: "",
      email: "",
      userName: "",
      get: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getdata();
  },
  methods: {
    getInfo() {
      this.get = true;
    },

    async getdata() {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const json = await res.json();
      this.data = json;
      this.nameUser = this.data;
      console.log(this.data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
<style>
.user {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.info {
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.oneuser {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </nav>
    <div class="user" v-for="users of data" :key="users.id">
      <p class="oneuser">{{ users.name }}</p>
      <button class="info" @click="getInfo(users.id)">+</button>
    </div>
    <div v-for="info of data" :key="info.id">
      <div v-if="get == info.id">
        <p>{{ info.username }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [],
      nameUser: "",
      email: "",
      userName: "",
      get: -1,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getdata();
  },
  methods: {
    getInfo(id) {
      this.get = id;
    },

    async getdata() {
      const res = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
      const json = await res.json();
      this.data = json;
      this.nameUser = this.data;
      console.log(this.data);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Здравствуете, я решил скопировать ваш код, чтобы проверить как он работает, но мне выдало гору ошибок, может я что-то не то скопировал?((

Comment: Я кажется починил и понял, у вас просто при нажатии на кнопку выводит информацию обо всех пользователях, но только под именем рядом с которым была нажата кнопка. А мне бы хотелось, чтобы вывело информацию только об определенном человеке и только о нем, чтобы об остальных ничего не писало и так со всеми

Comment: Тогда пусть переменная get будет равна номеру пользователя. И показывать только ту инфу, номер которой совпадает с номером пользователя. Поправил.

Comment: всё равно он ругается в консоле не что-то(

Comment: Всё, я во всем разобрался, спасибо вам большое